# Getting total search count done with algolia

Tags: php, curl, algolia

I am having trouble with getting total search count from start to till now within all indexes.
Can anyone please tell me how can i get this statistic from algolia api.

Answer (score 0):

Algolia is working on a monitoring API to fetch such data but it's not yet available. For now, you'll need to use the graphs displayed in your Algolia dashboard.

Comment: I got that search count within an index and within a start time and end time but i need it for all index and of course it's available see "Analytics API" from doc section.